# Depressed last plot in pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, graphics

For some reason, the rightmost graph is slightly lower than the other graphs, but I don't know why.

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{1em}
\begin{tabular}[ht]{m{8em} m{8em} m{8em} m{8em}}

\begin{tikzpicture} %y=x

\begin{axis}[grid=both,
axis lines=middle,
ticklabel style={fill=white,font=\scriptsize},
x=0.8cm,y=0.8cm,clip=false,
xmin=-2,xmax=2,xtick={-1,1},
ymin=-2,ymax=2,ytick={-1,1},
xlabel=\(x\),ylabel=\(y\),
samples=2]

\addplot[domain=-2:2,<->,>=latex] {x};

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

&
\begin{tikzpicture} %y=x^2

\begin{axis}[grid=both,
axis lines=middle,
ticklabel style={fill=white,font=\scriptsize},
x=0.8cm,y=0.8cm,clip=false,
xmin=-2,xmax=2,xtick={-1,1},
ymin=-1,ymax=3,ytick={1,2},
xlabel=\(x\),ylabel=\(y\),
samples=200]

\addplot[domain=-1.732:1.732,<->,>=latex] {x^2};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

&
\begin{tikzpicture} %y=x^3

\begin{axis}[grid=both,
axis lines=middle,
ticklabel style={fill=white,font=\scriptsize},
x=0.8cm,y=0.8cm,clip=false,
xmin=-2,xmax=2,xtick={-1,1},
ymin=-2,ymax=2,ytick={-1,1},
xlabel=\(x\),ylabel=\(y\),
samples=200]

\addplot[domain=-1.260:1.260,<->,>=latex] {x^3};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

&
\begin{tikzpicture} %y=x^4

\begin{axis}[grid=both,
axis lines=middle,
ticklabel style={fill=white,font=\scriptsize},
x=0.8cm,y=0.8cm,clip=false,
xmin=-2,xmax=2,xtick={-1,1},
ymin=-1,ymax=3,ytick={1,2},
xlabel=\(x\),ylabel=\(y\),
samples=200]

\addplot[domain=-1.316:1.316,<->,>=latex] {x^4};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

This yields the following image.

[image]

Comment: Aside from [ht] instead of [t] in the tabular (no h allowed), it worked fine for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is the images in the other columns. They have an empty line at the end after `\end{tikzpicture}`. This empty line ends the paragraph. Then a strut (for the depth) is inserted by the tabular, which starts a new paragraph.

Version with `\hline`s to illustrate the table row:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{1em}
\begin{tabular}[t]{m{8em} m{8em} m{8em} m{8em}}
\hline
\begin{tikzpicture} %y=x

\begin{axis}[grid=both,
axis lines=middle,
ticklabel style={fill=white,font=\scriptsize},
x=0.8cm,y=0.8cm,clip=false,
xmin=-2,xmax=2,xtick={-1,1},
ymin=-2,ymax=2,ytick={-1,1},
xlabel=\(x\),ylabel=\(y\),
samples=2]

\addplot[domain=-2:2,<->,>=latex] {x};

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
&
\begin{tikzpicture} %y=x^2

\begin{axis}[grid=both,
axis lines=middle,
ticklabel style={fill=white,font=\scriptsize},
x=0.8cm,y=0.8cm,clip=false,
xmin=-2,xmax=2,xtick={-1,1},
ymin=-1,ymax=3,ytick={1,2},
xlabel=\(x\),ylabel=\(y\),
samples=200]

\addplot[domain=-1.732:1.732,<->,>=latex] {x^2};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
&
\begin{tikzpicture} %y=x^3

\begin{axis}[grid=both,
axis lines=middle,
ticklabel style={fill=white,font=\scriptsize},
x=0.8cm,y=0.8cm,clip=false,
xmin=-2,xmax=2,xtick={-1,1},
ymin=-2,ymax=2,ytick={-1,1},
xlabel=\(x\),ylabel=\(y\),
samples=200]

\addplot[domain=-1.260:1.260,<->,>=latex] {x^3};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
&
\begin{tikzpicture} %y=x^4

\begin{axis}[grid=both,
axis lines=middle,
ticklabel style={fill=white,font=\scriptsize},
x=0.8cm,y=0.8cm,clip=false,
xmin=-2,xmax=2,xtick={-1,1},
ymin=-1,ymax=3,ytick={1,2},
xlabel=\(x\),ylabel=\(y\),
samples=200]

\addplot[domain=-1.316:1.316,<->,>=latex] {x^4};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

The white space below the images can be avoided by lowering the images by an amount larger than the depth of a strut, e.g. via option `baseline` for all images:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=2em]
```

> [image: Fixed result]